# How to insert a single backslash in ruby when string come from URI decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have encoded the encrypted value to pass the value by url like this

```
"%5Cx9DJ%5CxB2%3Dr%5Cx81%5CxDA%5Cx96T%5CxA1%7E%5CxE8d7%5Cx81%5Cx91"
```

but when i decoded the value ruby return string like this

```
"\\x9DJ\\xB2=r\\x81\\xDA\\x96T\\xA1~\\xE8d7\\x81\\x91"
```

instead of this

```
"\x9DJ\xB2=r\x81\xDA\x96T\xA1~\xE8d7\x81\x91"
```

how can i convert double backslashes to a single backslash ?

i already try gsub ('\\'){'\'} but it returned the same value

here is my code

```
 encrypted_value = URI.decode("%5Cx9DJ%5CxB2%3Dr%5Cx81%5CxDA%5Cx96T%5CxA1%7E%5CxE8d7%5Cx81%5Cx91")
@decrypted_id=Encryptor.decrypt(encrypted_value, :key => secret_key, :iv => iv, :salt => salt)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code for decoding the value and for displaying it.

Comment: okay edited @MichaelBurr

Comment: The problem is in how you are displaying `encrypted_value`.  When I do `puts URI.decode("%5Cx9DJ%5CxB2%3Dr%5Cx81%5CxDA%5Cx96T%5CxA1%7E%5CxE8d7%5Cx81%5Cx91")` I get what you expect..

Comment: Yes when i puts it in console i got what i expect but I need to use encrypted_value for decryption not to display thanks @Michael Burr

Comment: I understand that you need to decrypt it - what I'm saying is that it has the value you expect it to have from URI decoding the original string.  You have some other problem than doubled backslashes.  Perhaps you need to convert the `\x` sequence to bytes with the specified hexadecimal value?

Comment: But i can encrypt the specific string "\x9DJ\xB2=r\x81\xDA\x96T\xA1~\xE8d7\x81\x91"

Comment: If `"\x9DJ\xB2=r\x81\xDA\x96T\xA1~\xE8d7\x81\x91"` is a literal in your Ruby source, then the interpreter will create the string object with binary data for the `\x` escape sequences. However, the string object you are getting back from `URI.decode()` has the `\x` sequences in the string object - since that string is merely data, not a string literal. You need to run the string through another step to translate the escape sequences to the binary data (as I suggested a couple comments above). You need to wrap your head around how string literals in the source differ from string data objects.

Comment: yeah it finally works, i need to covert this string to actual bytes. thank you @MichaelBurr!

Answer (score 0):

It's a confusing display issue. You don't have to change anything and the value should work for decryption. However, when you print the value, it'll show up as `\\` as the first `\` is a reserved escape character.